# When and where can you catch Salmon and King Salmon?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

When exactly can you catch Salmon and King Salmon?

The guidebook (which is notoriously unreliable) says Sea (early September) River (late September).

Is it anywhere in the sea?  Or just under the waterfall?

When does early September become late September?

Other sources seem to have mixed answers on this.

Comment: If it helps anyone, I caught a Salmon and a King Salmon under the waterfall in the ocean on September 6th.  I'd still like to know what the exact requirements are for them to appear though.

Answer (score 1):

According to [IGN's guide](http://www.ign.com/wikis/animal-crossing-new-leaf/September), King Salmon are most common in the first two weeks of September, catchable all day at the River Mouth. They exist but are less common the second two weeks of the summer. Salmon it claims is catchable in the River, but more common at the River Mouth, the month of September only.

Answer (score 0):

I've only ever caught salmon at the waterfall feeding the river and the waterfall feeding into the sea. One thing I did notice, and it may be a fluke, is that they are more likely to appear in the waterfall feeding the sea if you swim out to the little land mass next to the waterfall only accessible if you have a diving suit.